# Adding a validation for an already existing data in my CodeIgniter application doesn't work

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter web application that takes student information and saves them in a table named `student`. My table structure is this:

```
   name             varchar(30)
   roll             varchar(10)
   department       varchar(10)
   email            varchar(50)

   mobile           varchar(15)
```

In my application, I want to achieve the following behavior:

While inserting data, if roll data already exists, then a validation will appear next to the roll text field saying *This roll number already exists. Please enter a new roll*. That means, for duplicate entries of roll data, a validation will appear, and that data will not be inserted.

My controller is `student.php`, note that it contains a callback function and a validation rule:

```
 <?php
 if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')){ exit('No direct script access allowed');}
 class Student extends CI_Controller
 {
     function __construct()
     {
         parent::__construct();
         #$this->load->helper('url');
         $this->load->model('student_model');
         $this->load->library('form_validation');
         $this->load->library('session');
     }

     //Show all Students
     public function index()
     {
         $data['student_list'] = $this->student_model->get_all_students();
         $this->load->view('student_view', $data);
     }


     //Insert a student
     public function insert_student_db()
     {
         $udata['name'] = $this->input->post('name');
         $udata['roll'] = $this->input->post('roll');
         $udata['department'] = $this->input->post('department');
         $udata['email'] = $this->input->post('email');
         $udata['mobile'] = $this->input->post('mobile');

         $this->form_validation->set_rules('roll', 'Roll', 'callback_check_duplicate_roll');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) 
        {
             $res = $this->student_model->insert_student($udata);
             if($res)
             {
                 header('location:'.base_url()."index.php/student/".$this->index());

             }

         }
         else
         {
             $this->session->set_flashdata('warning', 'Data already exists');
             redirect('/student/index/', 'refresh');
         }

    }

    // My callback function
    public function check_duplicate_roll($post_roll) 
    {
        return $this->student_model->checkDuplicateRoll($post_roll);
    }

}
?>
```

And my model is `student_model.php`, note that I've a method for checking duplicate roll data:

```
    <?php
    class Student_model extends CI_Model 
    {
         function __construct()
         {
              parent::__construct();
              $this->load->database();
         }  

         //To retrieve all students
         public function get_all_students()
         {
             $query = $this->db->get('student');
             return $query->result();
         }

         //Checking for duplicate roll
         public function checkDuplicateRoll($post_roll) 
         {
              $this->db->where('roll', $roll);
              $query = $this->db->get('student');
              $count_row = $query->num_rows();
              if ($count_row > 0) 
              {
                  return FALSE;
              } 
              else 
              {
                  return TRUE;
              }
         }


         //To add a new student to the database
         public function insert_student($data)
         {
             return $this->db->insert('student', $data);

         }

    }
    ?>
```

My view page - `student_view.php`:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>My first site in CI</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h2>Student Information</h2>
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/student/insert_student_db">
  <table width="800" border="0">
  <tr>
  <th width="213" align="right" scope="row">Name:</th>
  <td width="161"><input type="text" name="name" size="60" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th align="right" scope="row">Roll:</th>
  <td><input type="text" name="roll" size="60" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th align="right" scope="row">Department:</th>
  <td>
  <select name="department">
  <?php 
       $sql = mysql_query("SELECT dept_name FROM department");
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
             echo "<option value=\"{$row['dept_name']}\">" . $row['dept_name'] . "</option>";
       }
  ?></select>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th align="right" scope="row">Email:</th>
  <td><input type="text" name="email" size="60" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th align="right" scope="row">Mobile:</th>
  <td><input type="text" name="mobile" size="60" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th align="right" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
  <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" /></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
  <table width="600" border="1" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
  <th scope="col">Name</th>
  <th scope="col">Roll</th>
  <th scope="col">Department</th>
  <th scope="col">Email</th>
  <th scope="col">Mobile</th>
  </tr>
  <?php foreach ($student_list as $std_key){ ?>
  <tr>
  <td><?php echo $std_key->name; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $std_key->roll; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $std_key->department; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $std_key->email; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $std_key->mobile; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php }?>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

After I run my application in localhost and try to insert data, duplicate roll data is not inserted in my `student` table, that's fine, and my page is redirected to `student_view.php`. But the flash message doesn't show up. What is the problem? Is it a problem with my misplacement of flashdata? Or something else?

Note that this is the final, fully modified version of my question. I've edited this question 4 times ever since I first posted it, and because of all those edits, it looked ugly. So I've decided to trim my question according to the last updated version of my code. Please excuse the nature of this question and my inability to figure out the problem, cause I'm an absolute newby to CodeIgniter. Your kind help is going to help me understand CI and encourage me to carry on this journey.

Comment: You have set it, but you never get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your present code, the validation is no where to be found. Initialize the library in your controller first:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
```

And then when everything is okay, setting rules, etc.:

```
if($this->form_validation->run() !== false) {
    $res = $this->student_model->insert_student($udata);
}
```

For more info: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#validationrules

EDIT:

Since you have your own validation, you could use that custom validation too:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('roll', 'Roll', 'callback_checkDuplicateRoll');
```

and in your custom funtion:

```
public function checkDuplicateRoll($post_roll) 
{
    $this->db->where('roll', $roll);
    $query = $this->db->get('student');
    $count_row = $query->num_rows();
    if ($count_row > 0) 
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('checkDuplicateRoll', 'This roll number already exists. Please enter a new roll.');
        return FALSE;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But now a new problem has arisen. I'm still getting duplicate roll number inserted into the database. Means the validation is not working. Is there any more problems with my code?

Comment: @CrescentMoon thats a custom validation, check my revisiob

Comment: @CrescentMoon yes i made the revision again, i changed it, anyway i think you got it now

Comment: no luck mate. Changed my code according to your instruction, still getting duplicate roll inserted.

Comment: The callback function for form validation must be defined in the controller

Comment: @Gervs I think I've already done it. Still, you can point it out more specifically and show where exactly my problem is.

Comment: @CrescentMoon sorry for this late reply, i was afk for a while i needed my exercise 21k hehe, anyway i think the validation function is wrong, `>0` must be false rather than true, thats why when there is a duplicate it should be false

Comment: @CrescentMoon and check duplicate function must be in the controller by the way

Comment: @Ghost, it's ok mate. Exercise keeps you healthy and fit, good thing you do it. :D Anyways, I already did what you said, sorry I didn't update it in my post, and still no luck. Thanks for pointing it out anyways.

Answer (score 2):

student.php

```
public function checkDuplicateRoll($roll) {
    return $this->student_model->checkDuplicateRoll($roll);
}
```

If you define a callback function in a validation rule, the validator will call a function in the class where the validation rules are set. In this case Student controller.

**Edit**

Controller student.php:

```
public function insert_student_db() {
    // check if form is posted and assing variable to post data
    if (false !== $udata = $this->input->post()) {
        //unset the submit button
        unset($udata['submit']);
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('roll', 'Roll', 'callback_check_duplicate_roll');
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_duplicate_roll', 'Role already exists');
        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $this->student_model->insert_student($udata);
            redirect('index.php/student');
        }
        else {
            $this->load->helper('form');
            $this->load->view('studentForm');
        }
    }
}

//for some reason a callback function needs to be public
public function check_duplicate_roll($roll) {
    return $this->student_model->checkDuplicateRoll($roll) == false;
}
```

Model student_model.php

```
public function ckeckDuplicateRoll($roll) {
    $this->db->select('roll');
    $this->db->where('roll', $roll);
    $result = $this->db->get('student');
    return (bool) $result->num_rows();
}
```

**Views in CodeIgniter**

As a matter of fact it's MVC where talking about, but a view shouldn't contain any programming logic, except for some echoes (optional in an iteration), some minor calculations and some condtional statements.
It's the controller that interacts with the model(s), and parses the data obtained to the view.
In CI it's quite simple:

```
public function index() {
    $data = array('title' => 'My first CI site',
                  'header' => 'First attempt',
                  'departments' => $this->m_departments->getCollection()
                  );
    $this->load->view('student_view', $data);
}
```

CI runs $data through extract (core php function), so the keys becomes variables which contains the value. You can use these variables in the view:

```
// departments as example
<select name="department">
<?php
     foreach($departments as $row) {
         echo '<option value="' . $row['dept_name'] . '">' . $row['dept_name'] . '</option>';
     }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't have a `studentform`. Please check my view file in my edit. Thank you once again.

Comment: The example I gave was meant to put you in the right direction. Please check the link in Ghost's answer how to work with form validation and the form helper. And (as a friendly advice) take a tour through the whole documentation, i think you might want to learn more about the MVC pattern.

Comment: Thank you very much @Gervs. Well, of course I'll do that, coz I'm an absolute beginner to CodeIgniter. But I wanted to get a 'hands-on' experience on working in CI, that's why, I went for building something by myself rather than reading the whole CI User guide. And, although I know about MVC, I need to fine-tune my knowledge of MVC a lot more. So your advice is a very useful and valuable one.

Comment: You don't have to read the complete documentation, but if you use some functionallity, you might read that section. It will save you a lot of trouble. I've extended my answer with a simple example how to work with views.

Comment: Most kind of you @Gervs. Thank you so much for giving so much time to explain this to me. :)